# Is a function still a function if it doesn't have any rule?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

From what I've read on the internet, I've concluded that function differs from relation in that function can only have one range per domain. So, if for example:

```
F={(1,3),(2,4),(3,6),(4,12)}
```

I don't think there's any rule in it ( f(x)=blabla ) cause I just randomly typed it out. As you can see, the F set has a perfect one-to-one correspondence. But since it doesn't have any rule, is it still considered a function?
Thanks!

Comment: Yes it is still a function!

Comment: @Emin Why? Can you cite any source?

Comment: What would you mean by a rule?

Comment: @ploosu2 for example: f(x)=3+2x. I don't know whether or not it's called a rule though lol

Comment: Most functions cannot be explicitly written as $f(x)=\text{some formula}$. It's normal, they are still functions.

Comment: Ok then never mind the sources, a consensus has been reached. A function it is then. Can someone write the answer?

Comment: Functions that have algebraic formula like that are called algebraic (I think). But there are others too. The domain of a function can be any set, for example {cat, dog, donkey} so in this case there isn't even any algebra involved with that set.

Comment: It is absolutely still a function even if it has no rule.  The only requirement for a relation $R$ to be a function is that $xRy \wedge xRz \implies y=z$; that is, there can't be more than one element of the range related to an element of the domain.

Comment: Wait, wait, wait. Why is this a function? I just see a set of tuples in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with no indication of something in the domain being mapped to something in the range. The set $R = \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ isn't a function. It's just a set.

Comment: @AmagicalFishy It's the settheoretic defintion of a function as ordered pairs. Some would call this the graph of the function.

Comment: Ah! Alright. That makes sense, thanks.

Comment: @ploosu2 That isn't the definition of an [algebraic function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AlgebraicFunction.html) at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only property that needs to have a relation to be a function is that (as you've said) function can only have one range per domain. Roughly speaking it 'means' that in a part of time (domain) you can be just in one place (range). It doesn't need to have any formal rule for a given relation (as $y=f(x)$) to be a function, it needs just to fulfill the condition of the definition. So yes, the given relation is a function.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, your function *does* have a rule--infinitely-many possible rules, in fact. For example, if $g(x)$ is *literally any function* $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R,$ we could say that $F$ is the function from $\{1,2,3,4\}$ to $\Bbb R$ given by $$F(x)=\frac{3(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)}{(1-2)(1-3)(1-4)}+\frac{4(x-1)(x-3)(x-4)}{(2-1)(2-3)(2-4)}+\frac{6(x-1)(x-2)(x-4)}{(3-1)(3-2)(3-4)}+\frac{12(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)}{(4-1)(4-2)(4-3)}+(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)g(x).$$ Letting $g(x)=0$ makes $F$ the unique polynomial function of degree $3$ passing through the $4$ points you gave, restricted to the $x$-values $1,2,3,4.$ See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial) for more.

A function need not have a rule, though. More generally, given sets $A$ and $B,$ we say that $f$ is a function from $A$ to $B$ if $f$ is a relation whose domain is $A,$ having $B$ as a codomain, and such that for every $x\in A$ there is a unique $y\in B$ such that $\langle x,y\rangle\in f$ (this is sometimes referred to as "the vertical line rule").